# First line indentation in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I do not manage to force sphinx to apply first line indentation to paragraphs with the ReadTheDoc theme. I tried

```
texinfo_elements = {'paragraphindent': 2}
```

but it does not seem to work. Is there another thing to do?

Comment: RTD theme is for HTML output only. texinfo is a different builder than html.

Comment: I would like to have first line indentation of paragraphs in the html output. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom style with [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent).

You can add this style to a `custom.css` file and include it in your `conf.py` as a configuration option [`html_css_files`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files).

### custom.css

```css
p {
  text-indent: 1em;
}
```

### conf.py

```python
html_css_files = ['custom.css']
```